# Non-restoring division algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary, division, bit, addition

Does anyone know the steps for dividing unsigned binary integers using non-restoring division?

It's hard to find any good sources online.

i.e if `A = 101110` and `B = 010111`

how do we find `A divided by B` in non-restoring division? What do the registers look like in each step?

Thanks!

Comment: @RaymondChen, wrong results

Answer (score 21):

(My answer is a little late-reply. But I hope it will be useful for future visitors)

Algorithm for Non-restoring division is given in below image :

[image]

In this problem, Dividend (A) = 101110, ie 46, and Divisor (B) = 010111, ie 23.

Initialization :

```
Set Register A = Dividend = 000000
Set Register Q = Dividend = 101110
( So AQ = 000000 101110 , Q0 = LSB of Q = 0 )
Set M = Divisor = 010111, M' = 2's complement of M = 101001
Set Count = 6, since 6 digits operation is being done here.
```

After this we start the algorithm, which I have shown in a table below :

In table, `SHL(AQ) denotes shift left AQ by one position leaving Q0 blank`.

Similarly, a square symbol in Q0 position denote, `it is to be calculated later`

[image]

Hope all the steps are clear from the table !!!

Comment: Just a reminder: It is *not* enough to adjust the remainder (A) if it ends up negative: decrement the quotient (Q) by one.

Answer (score 1):

1) Set the value of register A as 0 (N bits)
2) Set the value of register M as Divisor (N bits)
3) Set the value of register Q as Dividend (N bits)
4) Concatenate A with Q {A,Q}
5) Repeat the following “N” number of times (here N is no. of bits in divisor):
  If the sign bit of A equals 0,
   shift A and Q combined left by 1 bit and 
  *subtract* M from A,
  else shift A and Q combined left by 1 bit and *add* M to A
  Now if sign bit of A equals 0, then set Q[0] as 1, else set Q[0] as 0
6) Finally if the sign bit of A equals 1 then add M to A.
7) Assign A as remainder and Q as quotient.

Comment: This seems to just put into words the (incomplete) diagram from [Abid Rahman K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712244/3789665).

Comment: @greybeard: If it's accurate (I didn't check) that's useful for people using screen-readers or other technology that doesn't work for images of text.

Comment: (@PeterCordes: `[putting into words] useful for [more than one purpose]` been there, done that. Not my down-vote.)

Comment: @greybeard kindly check it's accurate and sometimes steps in points give better explanation as compared to a flow chart

Comment: (I don't see the point telling me: I have done the equivalent in other questions (and even claimed so above), I didn't down-vote, I don't see this answer as *not useful* (hover over "the down-vote-triangle).)