# Non-restoring division algorithm on 128bit/64bit

Tags: algorithm, assembly, binary, bit, division

I am trying to implement non-restoring division 128bit number by 64bit,i use the  32bit register. I use algorithm explanation from this link [Non-restoring division algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133810/non-restoring-division-algorithm)  but I have some problem with initialization.

**1** I have 128bit/64bit so how many counts I must set 128?
**2** How many bits I need for register **A**, 128?

Answer (score 0):

1. All in 128bits.
2. Yes

The algorithm presented in that link is for unsigned numbers. The use of the expression "A < 0?" can be confusing. I would use "MSB(A) = 1?" or similar instead.